# retrieve selectize object declared in separate file

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

On some point of page going `selectize` initialization.

```
     somewhere in file 1
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $tagSelectize = $('.assign-tags').selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            valueField: 'original_name',
            labelField: 'name',
            ...all options not relative to the topic
        });
    });
```

I need add option in another part of the code and I do this:

```
file 2
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var tso1 = $('.assign-tags').selectize;
        var tso = tso1[0].selectize;
        tso.addOption({value:100, text: 'BBBBB'});
        tso.refreshOptions();
        tso.addItem(100);

    });


</script>
```

but that completely rewrites previous instance and replace by new. How can I retrieve inited `selectize` in file 1

Comment: What is `tso` can you show the `console.log(tso)`?

Comment: @bkr it throws a ```TypeError``` before the tso variable is filled because tso1 is an object and don't have a "0" property

Answer (score 0):

I think that on file 2 you should change

```
var tso1 = $('.assign-tags').selectize;
var tso = tso1[0].selectize;
```

with
`var tso = $('.assign-tags')[0].selectize;`

because what you are sayng is

> take the fist element of the **Array** `$('.assign-tags').selectize` and then take it's *"selectize"* property

but I think that you meant

> take the first `$('.assign-tags')` element (ie `$('.assign-tags')[0]`) and from it take the *"selectize"* property

so file 2 should become something like the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tso1 = $('.assign-tags')[0];
    var tso = tso1.selectize;
    tso.addOption({value:100, text: 'BBBBB'});
    tso.refreshOptions();
    tso.addItem(100);
});
```